# Cast object to dataRowView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid where every row is an object. I want to edit/delete a row. I get the selected row using this:

```
 DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dataGridIkuns.SelectedItem; // Selected row.
```

However, it throws the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'IkunDataBaseObject ' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

How can I take a row from the DataGrid?

This line works perfect before I changed my way to insert information to the data grid. I inserted information as objects before I load it from a Database Access.

My insert to the data grid :

```
ObservableCollection<IkunDataBaseObject> lstIkunsDB = 
    new ObservableCollection<IkunDataBaseObject>();

for (int counterIkunsDB = 0; counterIkunsDB < rowCount2; counterIkunsDB++)
{

    IkunDataBaseObject ikunTempDB = new IkunDataBaseObject(txtNumOfIkunDG, 
        txtNumOfRadarDG, txtObserverDG, txtLatDG, txtLongDG, 
        txtLatByCuttingDG, txtLongByCuttingDG, txtDeviationDG, 
        txtLatDeviation, txtLongDeveation);

    lstIkunsDB.Add(ikunTempDB);


}
dataGridIkuns.ItemsSource = lstIkunsDB;
```

Comment: Why don't you cast it to `IkunDataBaseObject` instead?

Comment: Just replace `DataRowView` with `IkunDataBaseObject` in your first line of code.

Comment: I want to add a new row, but there is no empty row to add information to datagrid. There is exactly rows in my information. Do you understand me ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned a row is an object, so you have to convert it to an IkunDataBaseObject object instead.
If you have the databindings set up correctly you could just take the object that is the selected item from the datagrid and delete it from the collection lstIkunsDB.

```
IkunDataBaseObject obj = (IkunDataBaseObject)dataGridIkuns.SelectedItem;
lstIkunsDB.Remove(obj);
```

For editing you should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the IkunDataBaseObject class roperties, then it should update the datagrid whenever you change a property in an object.